# How to get cosmos db gremlin endpoint in Terraform output

Tags: terraform, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure

We are using Terraform to generate endpoint and set to our service, we can get the document db connection string:
AccountEndpoint=https://mygraphaccount.documents.azure.com:443/

My question is how to get Gremlin Endpoint:
GremlinEndpoint: wss://mygraphaccount.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com:443/,

In the document of terraform:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account

```
id - The CosmosDB Account ID.

endpoint - The endpoint used to connect to the CosmosDB account.

read_endpoints - A list of read endpoints available for this CosmosDB account.

write_endpoints - A list of write endpoints available for this CosmosDB account.

primary_key - The Primary key for the CosmosDB Account.

secondary_key - The Secondary key for the CosmosDB Account.

primary_readonly_key - The Primary read-only Key for the CosmosDB Account.

secondary_readonly_key - The Secondary read-only key for the CosmosDB Account.

connection_strings - A list of connection strings available for this CosmosDB account.
```

None of these looks like GreminEndpoint.

Comment: Did you try deploying the TF file and see what came back as the endpoint? If so, what did it output (feel free to redact the actual Cosmos account name).

Comment: the output endpoint is: https://mygraphaccount.documents.azure.com:443/, now I get the account name: "mygraphaccount" and add "gremlin.cosmos.azure.com", so I can use: mygraphaccount.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com, Just want to know is this the right way to do so?

Comment: I did some checking and Cosmos DB does not output the Gremlin endpoint via its resource provider so TF isn't going to either. Given this I would say that what you are doing is the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with MongoDB and solved it by a custom string interpolation (as mentioned in the comments of the question).

```
output "gremlin_url" {
  value = "wss://${azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.name}.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com:443/"
}
```